# how take out \n when using a 'for' loop with a list?

Tags: python-3.5

How do I stop each word being printed out on a new line? I have tried stripping new line using word.strip("\n")

Answer (score 1):

`print` has an optional parameter to control the line end:

```
line = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
for word in line.split():
    print(word,end=',')
```

Output:

```
The,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over,the,lazy,dog,
```

Ref: [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)